# Creating UTC timestamps in sails without overriding 'createdAt' and 'updatedAt'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, momentjs

I want to update a field in one of my models with UTC timestamps (createTimeUTC). But I don't want to overwrite/override the 'createdAt' field. I tried importing moment and using moment.utc().format() to update the record on creation. But even though moment seems to be giving the proper UTC format timestamp, the record in database is still getting created as "null".

Here is my model:

module.exports = {

```
    attributes: {
        ....

            createTimeUTC: {
                type: 'datetime',
            },

      },
 afterCreate:function(values,next) {
    var moment=require('moment');
    values.createTimeUTC= moment.utc().format();
    console.log("after create: "+ values.createTimeUTC);
    next();
    };
```

Here is my create method in the controller:

```
myControllerMethod: function(req, res) {
        var moment=require('moment');
        var params = req.params.all();

        params.owner = req.session.user.id;

        Note.create({owner: params.owner, title: params.title, content: params.content, createTimeUTC: params.createTimeUTC }).exec(function(err, note) {
                    if(err) {
                        var msg = 'Unexpected error has occured';
                        sails.log.error(err);
                        res.status(400);
                        return res.send(msg);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("CREATED:"+note.createTimeUTC);
                        res.redirect("/admin/notes/scratchpad");    
                        }
        });
    },
```

Can someone please point where am I going wrong?

And also, is there a way to just convert "createdAt" time to UTC in the front-end than having to create new fields in the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply changing the values in the `afterCreate` handler won't finalize the changes. The `values` object isn't a model instance but a simple object. To save the newly created field, you need to make another database call in `afterCreate`:

```
afterCreate: function(values, next) {
    var moment = require('moment');
    values.createTimeUTC= moment.utc().format();
    Note.update({ id: values.id }, values, next);
};
```

As far as changing the time format in the front-end is concerned, you can do that in your view if it supports date-related filters. If server-side rendering isn't possible, the only alternative would be to show/update the date/time after the page loads, using plain JS.

If you want the formatted date to appear every time you access the model, it might make sense to do the formatting in the model's `toJSON` function:

```
toJSON: function(){
    var moment=require('moment');
    var obj = {};
    obj.field = this.field;//for all other fields
    obj.createdAt = moment.utc(this.createdAt).format();
    return obj;
}
```

Place this inside the `attributes` section of your model.

**NOTE**: If you wish to preserve the date/time format while saving to the database, use type `string` instead of `datetime` in the model, otherwise it will still reflect the date/time string of the configured locale.

Comment: I'm getting an error "Callback was already called" with the above answer. I think there is something wrong in the afterCreate's call to next();. I reverted this and tried running update from my controller since I was able to get the UTC value there. But it didn't update the UTC time in database.

Comment: Ah, that was very stupid on my part. Edited the code. Had called `next()` twice by mistake. Can you try this again?

Comment: I tried it. But it updates the database with PDT time, not UTC. I am wondering if I should use afterValidate instead of afterCreaate. 'afterValidate' is atleast attempting to update the database and gives the following error: 'Incorrect datetime value: '2015-07-22T17:39:27+00:00' for column 'createTimeUTC' at row 1

Comment: It doesn't update as PDT, just shows as PDT since it's a datetime field. You could either store create createTimeUTC as a string instead of datetime or do the formatting in the views or after page load.

Comment: I totally trusted the datatype. Nice catch.. Thank you for quick responses. I am accepting your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Working on this further, I found that `createdAt` and `updatedAt` times are already stored as UTC in MySQL by sails (prints in UTC on console although visible as PDT in views). So I just needed to use `moment.utc(note.createdAt).format()` in my view to display the time in UTC. As far as the behavior of sails with MySQL database is concerned, [this](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/688) discussion gives some understanding.